# Unable to clear all previous activities and jump out apps

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

i called

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Main_AllLatestNews.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

However, when i click back button in `Main_AllLatestNews` class, it should be go out of apps instead of back to previous activity.

Comment: what u want to say i think u are not a clear first u ask unable to clear all top of activities and in detail u wright on click back button in Main_AllLatestNews class, it should be go out of apps instead of back to previous activity.

Comment: but in description what u have wrote that u want to go in previous activity on back pressed  it should be go out of apps instead of back to previous activity. update this too what u want if u clear previous activity than not able to go to previous activity on back presses

Comment: A > B > C > D. In D i back to A, then i want go out apps but it will back to C.

Comment: in activity D by pressing back button u go to A activity or by other click event

Comment: back button because i set back to D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Activity D use code as shown below

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // do something on back.
        this.finish();
        Intent i = new Intent(Dactivity.this, AActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Backpressed destroy the current activity 

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            // do something on back.
            this.finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Main_AllLatestNews.class);

            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: i just call `finish()` then can destroy current activity ? but not previous stack

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Main_AllLatestNews.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
activity.startActivity(intent);
activity.finish();
```

Comment: `activity.finish()` is just destroy current activity but not previous in the stack